# how to replace the part of string from NSMutablestring

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one application.In that i take the string from array and replace .xml from that string and go to next page.And if i come back and execute that code the application will be crashed at that replace string line.Below is my code.

```
  -(void)open:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
  {
       NSInteger i=(recognizer).view.tag;
       NSMutableString *s1=[listoflessons objectAtIndex:i];
       [default1 setObject:s1 forKey:@"KeyToXmlFile"];
       NSLog(@"%@",[default1 objectForKey:@"KeyToXmlFile"]);
        [s1 replaceCharactersInRange:[s1 rangeOfString: @".xml"] withString: @""];
        [default1 setObject:s1 forKey:@"KeyToSelectedFile"];
        [listoflessons removeObjectAtIndex:i];
      [listoflessons insertObject:[default1 objectForKey:@"KeyToXmlFile"] atIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",listoflessons);
       SecondViewCOntroller *snd=[[SecondViewCOntroller    alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewCOntroller" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:snd animated:YES];
      }
```

so please tell me how to avoid that one.

Comment: while I try to figure out your code (oof), what ***IS*** the crash?

Comment: Not enough info. What exception are you getting?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with replaceCharactersInRange:withString:'

Comment: what is `listoflessons` declared as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my guess is that the objects in "listoflessons" are of type NSString and not NSMutableString.

try replacing this line:

```
   NSMutableString *s1=[listoflessons objectAtIndex:i];
```

with this:

```
   NSMutableString *s1=[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[listoflessons objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Comment: No they are also NSMutableString objects

Comment: listoflessons is an array, true. but maybe the objects in it are not. i'll edit my answer

Comment: NSMutableString *str=[list objectAtIndex:k];
 [listoflessons addObject:str];

Comment: It's Working.Great.Thank U.And i am using xcode 4.3.In this if i write release  then error will come because this contain the ARC.Is ther any problem if we create more number of objects at anywhere based on our requirment.

Comment: since you are using ARC, it shouldn't cause a problem. you can also use [NSMutableString stringWithString:...], if it makes you more comfortable.